# How to give certain rows 'points' depending on how much larger that row's column 1 is compared to that row's column 2

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I'm looking at creating an algorithm where if the views_per_hour is 2x larger than the average_views_per_hour, I give the channel 5 points; if it is 3x larger I give the row 10 points and if it is 4x larger, I give the row 20 points. I'm not really sure how to go about this and would really appreciate some help.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'channel':['channel1','channel2','channel3','channel4'], 'views_per_hour_today':[300,500,2000,100], 'average_views_per_hour':[100,200,200,50],'points': [0,0,0,0] })

df.loc[:, 'average_views_per_hour'] *= 2
df['n=2'] = np.where((df['views_per_hour'] >= df['average_views_per_hour']) , 5, 0)

df.loc[:, 'average_views_per_hour'] *= 3
df['n=3'] = np.where((df['views_per_hour'] >= df['average_views_per_hour']) , 5, 0)

df.loc[:, 'average_views_per_hour'] *= 4
df['n=4'] = np.where((df['views_per_hour'] >= df['average_views_per_hour']) , 10, 0)
```

I expected to be able to add up the results from columns n=2, n=3, n=4 for each row in the 'Points' column but the columns are always showing either 5 or 10 and never 0 (the code thinks that the views_per_hour is always greater than the average_views_per_hour, even when the average_views_per_hour is multiplied by a large integer.)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of solving this kind of problem. You can use numpy select which has more concise syntax, you can also define a function and apply on the data frame.

```
div = df['views_per_hour_today']/df['average_views_per_hour']
cond = [(div >= 2) & (div < 3), (div >= 3) & (div < 4), (div >= 4) ]
choice = [5, 10, 20]
df['points'] = np.select(cond, choice)


    channel     views_per_hour_today    average_views_per_hour  points
0   channel1    300                     100                     10
1   channel2    500                     200                     5
2   channel3    2000                    200                     20
3   channel4    100                     50                      5
```